# TSQL Parameter for specific timeframes (day previous 4PM to today noon)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am looking to create a TSQL Parameter for specific timeframes such as MorningTimeFrame will pull yesterday from 4PM until noon today and AfternoonTimeFrame to pull noon today until 4Pm Today. How would I set that up? I'm familiar with the Dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) but not sure how I would set it to a specific time.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get these required timeframe values as per below query

```
Select Cast(Cast(CAST(dateadd(d,-1,getdate()) AS date) as varchar) + ' 16:00:00' as datetime)AS 'MorningStartTime', Cast(Cast(CAST(getdate() AS date) as varchar) + ' 12:00:00' as datetime)AS 'MorningEndAfterNoonStartTime', Cast(Cast(CAST(getdate() AS date) as varchar) + ' 16:00:00' as datetime)AS 'AfterNoonEndTime'
```

Use this as per convenience

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Will something simple suffice?

```
declare @Start as DateTime, @End as DateTime;
declare @Timeframe as VarChar(32) = 'MorningTimeframe';

-- Start from midnight today.
declare @Today as DateTime = Cast( GetDate() as Date );

-- Calculate the timeframe.
if @Timeframe = 'MorningTimeframe'
  begin -- Yesterday 4PM through noon today.
  select @Start = DateAdd( hour, -8, @Today ),
    @End = DateAdd( hour, 12, @Today );
  end
else if @Timeframe = 'AfternoonTimeframe'
  begin -- Noon today through 4PM.
  select @Start = DateAdd( hour, 12, @Today ),
    @End = DateAdd( hour, 16, @Today );
  end
else
  begin
  RaIsError( 'Unexpected timeframe: ''%s''', 16, 42, @Timeframe );
  end;

-- Display the results.
select @Today as [Today], @Timeframe as Timeframe, @Start as [Start], @End as [End];
```

Comment: This wouldn't because it isn't guaranteed they will run it at noon, so it would need to look at exact time.

Comment: Begging your pardon, but your comment and question are unclear. Your question mentions a _parameter_, e.g. something that is passed to a stored procedure (SP), though with no reference to an SP or how it would be used. The comment refers to running the code at some time other than noon, but the code makes no assumption about the time of day when it is run. When you ran the code what values were incorrect?